# Android Accessibility talkback aways says "close navigation drawer" regardless of drawer state

Tags: android, navigation, accessibility, talkback

I have a navigation drawer in my app that works perfectly. However in Accessibility mode with Talkback enabled, when moving over the home button that opens and closes the navigation drawer, it always says "close navigation drawer", even when the drawer is closed and hidden. Is this a bug with Talkback? Or am I not setting the states properly?

Comment: Okay definitely not a talkback bug cuz I just tried using talkback on the Google+'s navigation drawer, and it says "open navigation drawer" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionBarDrawerToggle widget calls ActionBar.setHomeActionContentDescription(), which doesn't automatically update the content description under API 18 or the initial release of API 19. This was fixed in 4.4.2, but you can work around this in earlier versions by poking the action bar and forcing it to recompute its content description.

Try calling one of the following on your action bar (using support lib as necessary):

```
setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
setTitle(getTitle())
setSubtitle(getSubtitle())
```

Answer (score 2):

For posterity:

I had the same problem and Alanv's answer helped me.  another thing to be aware of, adding to that, is that you should be sure that you're calling through to `super.onDrawerOpened()` and `super.onDrawerClosed()` in your implementation of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

If you do not do this, then the base class methods will not be called, which in turn, will not set the Action Bar content description as desired.

See [the Source code for ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java) for details.